# How to get time from database in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

How do you execute a SQL statement from Rails 3?

For example, the SQL statement "SELECT CURRENT_TIME" gets the time (working in PostgreSQL).

`Model.find_by_sql("SELECT CURRENT_DATE")` returns a model object.

Comment: are you really seeking to get the time? Or is there a ulterior motive? Cause you can get the time from Ruby with Time.now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do what you are asking you can get a handle to the connection and just execute sql on it.

```
sql = "SELECT CURRENT_TIME"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value(sql)
```